# Inserting values into a column based on the second table

Tags: oracle10g

I have two tables table1, table2. Both the tables can be joined based on empID.

I have a new column in table1 called tabseqno. I want to update tabseqno of table1 with tabseqno from table2.

```
UPDATE TABLE1  SET TABLE1.TABSEQNO =TABLE2.TABSEQNO
WHERE TABLE1.EMPID= TABLE2.EMPID AND TABLE2.GROUPID=99
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either:

```
update table1 set table1.tabseqno =
  ( select table2.tabseqno from table2
    where table2.empid = table1.empid
    and table2.groupid = 99);
```

or:

```
update table1 set table1.tabseqno =
  ( select table2.tabseqno from table2
    where table2.empid = table1.empid
    and table2.groupid = 99)
where exists
  ( select table2.tabseqno from table2
    where table2.empid = table1.empid
    and table2.groupid = 99);
```

depending on what you want to happen if there is no matching table2 row for a table 1 row (the first statement will set table1.tabseqno to null, the second will not update those rows at all).

Both only work if the table2 subquery can only return a maximum of 1 row for any `empid`.

Comment: Tony thanks. How can I do global update. I want to update all the records in table1 with the column value from table2.

Comment: Use one of the 2 SQL statements I gave in my answer!